# c++ runtime dispatch of 2 sets of static constants

Tags: c++, static, runtime, constants, dispatch

**Motivation**

A CLI app tries to make use of [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). But depending on the stdout device this may not be appropriate so there is a `-t` option to use pure ASCII text.

The concept is just an example, this applies anywhere where we want to select from two or more sets of static constants at runtime.

The question is what is reasonable c++ technique to facilitate this cleanly.

**Desired usage Syntax**

This is indicative only, but it the constant "invocation" should be terse

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  // using derived class style here, but anything would do
  auto t = std::strcmp(argv[1], "-t") == 0 ? TxtTerminal() : BdTerminal();

  // here we want the syntax to be short
  std::cout << "text" << t.horiz << t.right_t << '\n';

}
```

**Already tried**

I have tried Base and Derived class style (as above) but there are issues. I can't put one set of constants in `TxtTerminal` and one in `BdTerminal` (which extends `TxtTerminal`).

- Using static constants doesn't work, because C++ doesn't support "late static binding" , so it always uses the constants of whichever class you have the instance of.
- Using member variables and proper instances of those classes (as hinted at above) doesn't work (nicely) either because the Derived class can't initialise the Base class members directly....
- Nor via its constructor initialiser list ...
- The derived class would have to pass the entire set to the base class constructor which then modifies the already (BaseClass)initialised values. Really awkward and long winded. I guess passing some `struct config { .. };` could work
- Similarly using a single class, putting both sets of constants in there in a `map<key,config>` and using a getter to retrieve the appropriate constant using a constructor initialised `bool textmode` member state variable.
- Maybe with a templated solution taking some template parameter? Well no, because this is a  runtime switch.
- Similar to the template idea would be some kind of solution with `using` aliases for 2 separate constant namespaces..same problem..compile time..not runtime.
- Using `variable templates` a bit like the [new c++20 maths constants](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/numbers) . Same problem, not runtime.

Of course all this `const`, ie strings of the control character for the "box drawing terminal" are just a bytes long each. Ideally these would just be compacted together as literal initialised `const char*` in the `.text` (linux) segment of the executable (`std::string` seems overkill). Wherever we compose these constants we would want easy `concatenation` to make the code readable and maintainable. That's not so easy with `const char*` string literals?

Many options, none seem great. Am I missing something obvious?

**EDIT** In response to questions below and also to the initial [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59430101/1087626) by @walnut here is some more fleshed out code using the "static non-instance" approach.

Some unsolved problems therein, see comments:

```
// NOTE this code compiles and runs, but doesn't quite do what we need
// see comments

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct TextMode {
  static inline const auto cls     = "TM cls";
  static inline const auto right_t = "TM right_t";
  static inline const auto left_t  = "TM left_t";
};

struct BlockDrawMode {
  static inline const auto cls     = "BD cls";
  static inline const auto right_t = "BD right_t";
  static inline const auto left_t  = "BD left_t";
};

struct Terminal {

  Terminal(bool textmode = true) { mode = textmode ? &text_mode : &block_drawing_mode; }

  // what is this type? some parent class of TextMode/BlockDrawMode?!
  // then we get the initilisation loop again...
  //    ???????    // could be a reference initilised in cstr initilisation, but that's a detail
  const TextMode* mode;

  static inline const auto text_mode          = TextMode{};
  static inline const auto block_drawing_mode = TextMode{};
  // obviously this needs to be ..              ^ BlockDrawMode
  // but then doesn't compile because there is no class hierarchy ...

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Terminal t{strcmp(argv[1], "-t") == 0};

  std::cout << t.mode->cls << '\n' << t.mode->right_t << '\n';

  // output  (-t makes no difference right now, due to the above issues)
  // TM cls
  // TM right_t

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:** I have added a [self answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431450/1087626) which uses `aggregate initialisation` to avoid a lot of the unwanted inheritance complications. Feels a bit "dirty", but looks clean and works fine?

Comment: `argv[1] == "-t"` will *always* be false, since you compare two *pointers* (and only the pointers themselves) that will never be equal. To compare C-style null-terminated strings use [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). And you should *always* check `argc` first to make sure that the corresponding `argv` element exists.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure, but that's not the point here, it was just illustrative. I will fix it in the question

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. You went straight into what you tried, without explaining the actual issue. And without that, those attempts appear out of context. Please provide [mre], since it's unclear what `TxtTerminal`, or `BdTerminal` is, and why the current (proposed) solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: Regarding "... the Derived class can't initialise the Base class members directly" and "the Derived class can't initialise the Base class members directly" While that's true, you *can* invoke a suitable base class constructor in the derived class constructor initializer list: `Derived() : Base() {}` (which of course works passing arguments as well). And if you just want to "re-use" a base class constructor then "use" it: `class Derived : public Base { public: using Base::Base; ... };`

Comment: It seems to me that your only issue is to provide different constants to use in Base/Derived classes, but that is easily solved by having a virtual getter for these constants that is used by the rest of the methods.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Re constructor initialiser list of derived...will that not still result in double initialisation? ie Base initialises, then Derived constructor runs and runs its initialisation which calls the specialised Base Constructor? Double initialisation is not allowed?

Comment: @OliverSchonrock Only the entry in the member initializer list, if present, is used to initialize the base class. There is no double initialization possible. Please add a more concrete code example. It seems you have some misunderstandings of how inheritance in C++ works that are hard to identify without some example.

Comment: It seems that most of your alternatives are viable, but you block somewhere. Show some example of your failed attempts.

Comment: @walnut Yes the virtual getter way will work. That's what I meant with the the `map` option. It will work, but it feels ridiculous, unless there is no better way. Really, all I need is 2 areas of `static const char*` memory in the `.text` segment which are dynamically selected between by a runtime variable, which "points" to either set. And I am having trouble expressing that.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I can make some of these work. Particularly the 5th option. a 2D `std::map` style member variable selected from with a virtual getter - or similar. However this all seems like total overkill. It's just a bunch totally `const` and `static` content. 2 Sets of `static const char*`. The only runtime/dynamic part is the selection between the 2 sets. My issue is I cannot see how to "runtime/dynamically" select between 2 "static/compile" time `struct`s of `const char*` values. I can put the first set in a `type` and the second in another `type` but how to select between them?

Comment: I have added a self answer below which uses `aggregate initialisation` to avoid a lot of the unwanted inheritance complications. Feels a bit "dirty", but looks clean and works fine?

Comment: Base initialization will be done only once. Either using a default constructor, or the constructor you use in the derived constructor initializer list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. @walnut provide some sample code below which shows that. I felt that an inheritance hierarchy was overkill here and didn't really help because the member variables are not inherited/overridden or in any way checked against each other for consistency without a whole bunch more boilerplate code. So I went with `aggregate initiliazation` which (if we allow C99/C++20 `designated initializers`) solves this challenge with the minimum of fuss and actually the best "override" checks , see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59431450/1087626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposed "self answer":

Here is a version that avoids the hierarchy complications of the `config structs`. Basically `aggregate initialization` to the rescue...

This final version shows some proper terminal control strings and some tweaks using a `ref to static inline struct`.  plus it uses `designated initialisers`. Note selective overrides from the Base Struct Config details would be possible if desired. All the "keys" are automatically checked at compile time, so prevent mistakes during maintenance.

```
struct Mode {
  const char* const esc           = "";
  const char* const cls           = "";
  const char* const bd_on         = "";
  const char* const bd_off        = "";
  const char* const underline_on  = "";

  const char* const black   = "";
  const char* const red     = "";
  const char* const green   = "";
  const char* const yellow  = "";
  const char* const blue    = "";
  const char* const magenta = "";
  const char* const cyan    = "";
  const char* const white   = "";

  const char* const reset   = "";

  const char        horiz         = '-';
  const char        vert          = '|';
  const char        right_t       = '|';
  const char        left_t        = '|';
  const char        bottom_t      = '|';
  const char        top_t         = '|';
  const char        intersec      = '|';
};

struct Terminal {
  static inline const Mode text_mode;
  // warning: this is a C99 extension until C++20 comes in
  // but it nicely compile checks and self documents the code
  // supported by gcc4.7, clang3.0 and msvc19.21
  static inline const Mode box_draw_mode{
      .esc           = "\x1b",
      .cls           = "\x1b[2J",
      .bd_on         = "\x1b(0",
      .bd_off        = "\x1b(B",
      .underline_on  = "\x1b[4m",

      .black   = "\x1b[30m",
      .red     = "\x1b[31m",
      .green   = "\x1b[32m",
      .yellow  = "\x1b[33m",
      .blue    = "\x1b[34m",
      .magenta = "\x1b[35m",
      .cyan    = "\x1b[36m",
      .white   = "\x1b[37m",

      .reset   = "\x1b[0m",

      .horiz    = '\x71',
      .vert     = '\x78',
      .right_t  = '\x75',
      .left_t   = '\x74',
      .bottom_t = '\x76',
      .top_t    = '\x77',
      .intersec = '\x6e',
  };

  const Mode& m;
  Terminal(bool textmode = true) : m{textmode ? text_mode : box_draw_mode} {}

};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  Terminal t1{true};
  Terminal t2{false};

  // usage
  // std::cout << t1.m.cls << '\n' << t1.m.right_t << '\n';
  // std::cout << t2.m.cls << '\n' << t2.m.right_t << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Here is a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Zxorr7) (note that clang>3 and gcc>4.7 compile the designated initialisers just fine already). Also note that the godbolt shows that on `-O3` the initializers get optimized away to the point were the `char` values just become inlined register loads. On O1 we can clearly see the strings laid out in `.text` segment and literally the only thing that happen during `Terminal` construction is the setting of a single pointer for `Mode& m` to point to one of the 2 structures: `mov qword ptr [rdi], rcx`.  Good?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I gather that what you are looking for is:
If there aren't any other differences in behavior requiring a virtual interface or inheritance, then you can just define a pointer member which is chosen for the correct implementation at construction:

```
struct Terminal {

    Terminal(/* parameters */) {
        chooseConfig(/* some arguments */);
    }

    static constexpr char config1[]{/*...*/};
    static constexpr char config2[]{/*...*/};

    const char* config;

    void chooseConfig(/*arguments*/) {
        config = /*condition*/ ? config1 : config2;
    };

    // use `config` everywhere

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Terminal terminal{/* arguments */};

    //...
}
```

If all instances of this class are supposed to share the same configuration and passing the arguments to choose the configuration each time is too cumbersome, then you can also make `config` and `chooseConfig` `static` and instead of calling it in the constructor, call it once in `main` with `Terminal::chooseConfig(/*arguments*/);`.

Comment: Yes, using the virtual dispatch that solves some of the challenges I had. ie how to initliase withour Base() and Derived() fighting each other. We are still converting `.text` segment `static` content into a "runtime member variable" `Base::config` .

Comment: Yes! There is one one "instance" of each (ie none really). No sense having any more.  That second thing you just added! That's more like what I "felt" should be possibke, but didn't know how to express it...I will play with that.

Comment: @OliverSchonrock It is just a pointer. Accessing it is exactly as fast as accessing the array directly, constant-folding optimizations aside. The second method has pretty much the same performance properties as the first one.

Comment: I tried with the `static` approach and put the code at end of my question at the top. I got stuck on similar stuff as during my original attempt on this route.... Can't seem to get away from inheritance?

Comment: The reaons my approach gets lots in "the inheritance weeds", compared to to yours is because yours is just an array of char* and mine is "labelled" struct. I need it to be that, see usage in main. a `std::map` or similar would then require a `class:enum` for the keys...and it cascades.... No way to keep it simple?

Comment: I have added a self answer below which uses `aggregate initialisation` to avoid a lot of the unwanted inheritance complications. Feels a bit "dirty", but looks clean and works fine?